# $\#NAE2SAT$ and $\oplus NAE2SAT$ complexity

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, counting-complexity

Deciding $2SAT$ is in $NL$ and $\#2SAT$ is $\#P$ complete while $\oplus2SAT$ is $\oplus P$ complete.
Deciding $SAT$-$2$-$NAE$ - every clause has exactly $2$ literals, is there an $NAE$ satisfying assignment to the formula - is in $Logspace$.

What is the complexity of counting versions - $\#NAE2SAT$ and $\oplus NAE2SAT$ - of this problem?

Comment: I think you can easily rewrite every 2-NAE clause as affine clauses (e.g., $x \vee y$ is satisfied iff $x \oplus y = 1$, $x \vee \neg y$ iff $x \oplus y = 0$ etc.) thus #SAT-2-NAE can be solved in ptime (it is a linear system of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$). See Creignou, N., & Hermann, M. (1996). Complexity of generalized satisfiability counting problems. Information and computation, 125(1), 1-12.

Comment: So the complexity is $\#L$-complete?

Comment: I do not know, I am not that comfortable to quickly intuit results on small complexity classes. Why would you say that? What have you tried? Maybe edit the question if you are looking at something more precise than what I already commented on.